# Proof generation in zk cryptocurrency

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, cryptocurrency

In a cryptocurrency with privacy e.g., zcash, where does proof generation take place? Can it happen in the client's device every time a transaction is performed?

If it happens in client's device, are there possibilities of malware compromising the privacy?

Comment: If the proof generated is compromised, then it will fail verification by anyone who tries to verify it - so it won't matter

Answer (score 1):

Taking Zcash as an example, the proof is generated on the spender side. If the running environment is not trusted, two things will happen.

1. Malware could extract private information, such as payment value, wallet address, from the device's storage or memory.
2. Malware  could tamper with the input of pre-compiled circuits, e.g., recipient address, public keys.

Answer (score -1):

In major privacy currencies, such as haircomb, the proof generation (hashing) occurs on the client device. It is not believed a malware could compromise this in a meaningful way.